# How should I modify the response to an HTTP request and easily access it before return it out from Observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm upgrading to Angular to version 5, I was using `@angular/http` before and now I need to update to `@angular/common/http` and use [`HttpClient`](https://angular.io/guide/http)

I already just make http requests in services (not in components) and that **makes them easy to reuse**

This is what I already have (from deprecated http)

```
return this.http.get(url, {headers: this.headers}).map(
      (response: Response) => {
        const data = response.json();
        // Does something on data.data
        
        // return the modified data:
        return data.data;
      }
    ).catch(
      (error: Response) => {
        return Observable.throw(error);
      }
    );
```

Now from what I learned from new `HttpClient` it's like I can't modify the response and give it to the component method which is subscribing to it.

**how should I modify the response to an HTTP request and easily access it before return it out from Observable?**

I just want the same ability to modify the response which I get from API... Like adding some item to it, or do some more stuff to it before returing it

Comment: what have you tried until now?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I tried to use pipe which sounds not working!

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Do you think I did not read that? :)

Comment: Could you just add to your question what you have tried with `pipe`? The problem is in that code.

Comment: Seems like it, as you havent posted any code done by yourself that uses the http client api

Comment: @AJT_82 Hello. I loved your cats' photos. they were cute and nice. You know, the only thing I need to have is the same functionality I already had by using the deprecated `http` package. I mean, mapping and modifying data before return it to my component

Comment: Have you tried Interceptor?

Comment: @ChauTran I'm trying them now. But that listen to all requests, not just one request.. I want each service has its own response modifier

Comment: I havent tried this but in theory you should be able to provide interceptor on Components level, just like Services

Answer (score 46):

It all depends on the version of RxJs. Angular 6 shipped with RxJs 6 - which means that the map()/catch() approach is no longer valid.

Instead, you have to use pipe + map()/catchError() as shown below:

**Before Angular 6 / RxJs 6 - classic Http use:**

```
return this.http.get(url, {headers: this.headers}).map(
  (response: Response) => {
    const data : SomeType = response.json() as SomeType;
    // Does something on data.data

    // return the modified data:
    return data.data; // assuming SomeType has a data properties. Following OP post
  }
).catch(
  (error: Response) => {
    throwError(error); // From 'rxjs'
  }
);
```

Should be changed to this:

**After Angular 6 / RxJs 6 - HttpClient migration:**

```
return this.http.get<SomeType>(url, {headers: this.headers})
  .pipe(
     map( response => {  // NOTE: response is of type SomeType
         // Does something on response.data
         // modify the response.data as you see fit.

         // return the modified data:
         return response; // kind of useless
     }),
     catchError( error => {
         return throwError(error); // From 'rxjs'
     })
  ); // end of pipe
```

In the pipe, map() will pick up the response object (already parsed from JSON) and catchError() will pick up the first error if the HTTP fails.

Also, note that your Headers need to be HttpHeaders object too.

Read on pipe, map and catchError in RxJs 6

Comment: Also you can use `throwError` instead of `Observable.throw`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to **handling errors** more efficiently, i writting below codes and error classes, please notice to the each part:

1. I make a folder errors and inside this folder make a class for each of errors, these errors can be 500 errors or 400 errors like blew image:

[image: Error Classes]

2. Make a class **app-error.ts** like below codes:

   ```
   export class AppError {
       constructor(public originalError?: any) { }
   }
   ```
3. Another error classes **extends from app-error.ts** class:

   ```
   // not-found-error.ts class
   import {AppError} from './app-error';

   export class NotFoundError extends AppError { }



   // conflict-error.ts class
   import {AppError} from './app-error';

   export class ConflictError extends AppError { }



   // internal-server-error.ts class
   import {AppError} from './app-error';

   export class InternalServerError extends AppError { }



   // bad-request-error.ts class
   import {AppError} from './app-error';

   export class BadRequestError extends AppError {
       constructor(public originalError?: any) {
           super(originalError);
       }

       get errors(): string[] {
           if (this.originalError)
               return this.originalError;

           return null;
       }
   }
   ```
4. If you want to access to base error or you can modify error, i do it inside latest class **bad-request-error.ts**
5. Then you can use these classes inisde service:

   ```
   import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
   import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
   import {HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

   import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
   import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
   import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
   import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

   import {AppError} from '../errors/app-error';
   import {BadRequestError} from '../errors/bad-request-error';
   import {NotFoundError} from '../errors/not-found-error';
   import {InternalServerError} from '../errors/internal-server-error';
   import {ConflictError} from '../errors/conflict-error';

   @Injectable()
   export class DataService {
       public headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

       constructor(public http: HttpClient, public url: string) { }

       get(id: number) {
           return this.http.get(`${this.url}/${id}`, {headers: this.headers})
                  .map((response) => response.json())
                  .catch(DataService.handleError);
       }

       create(resource) {
           return this.http.post(this.url, JSON.stringify(resource), {headers: this.headers})
                  .map((response) => response.json())
                  .catch(DataService.handleError);
       }

       update(id: number, resource) {
           return this.http.put(`${this.url}/${id}`, JSON.stringify(resource), {headers: this.headers})
                  .map((response) => response.json())
                  .catch(DataService.handleError);
       }

       remove(id: number) {
           return this.http.delete(`${this.url}/${id}`, {headers: this.headers})
                  .map((response) => response.json())
                  .catch(DataService.handleError);
       }

       public static handleError(error: Response) {
           switch (error.status) {
               case 400:
                   return Observable.throw(new BadRequestError(error));
               case 404:
                   return Observable.throw(new NotFoundError());
               case 409:
                   return Observable.throw(new ConflictError());
               case 500:
                   return Observable.throw(new InternalServerError());

               default:
                   return Observable.throw(new AppError(error));
           }
       }
   }
   ```
6. Above code is the best code for **error handling and using map operator for manipulating response in success manner**.
7. And the latest pace is using service inside component like below code:

   ```
   import {Component} from '@angular/core';
   import {OnInit} from '@angular/core';
   import {HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';

   import {DataService} from '../../services/data.service';

   import {AppError} from '../errors/app-error';
   import {BadRequestError} from '../errors/bad-request-error';
   import {NotFoundError} from '../errors/not-found-error';
   import {InternalServerError} from '../errors/internal-server-error';
   import {ConflictError} from '../errors/conflict-error';

   @Component({
       selector: 'app-data',
       templateUrl: './data.component.html',
       styleUrls: ['./data.component.css']
   })
   export class DataComponent implements OnInit {

       constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
       }

       ngOnInit() {
           this.dataService.get(123).subscribe(
               (response: DataModel) => {
                   // ...
               },
               (error: AppError) => {
                   if (error instanceof NotFoundError) {
                       // ...
                   } else if (error instanceof BadRequestError) {
                       // ...
                   } else if (error instanceof ConflictError) {
                       // ...
                   } else {
                       // ...
                   }
               }
           );
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

My service

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
    getData()
    {
        return this.http.get('../assets/data.json').map(data=>{
            return this.process(data);
        }).catch(
            (error: Response) => {
              return Observable.throw(error);
            });
    }
    process(data:any)  
    {
        let dataTransform:any[]=[];
        let i:number=0;
        for (let item of data)
        {
            dataTransform.push({"id":i,"key":item.key});
            i++;
        }
        return dataTransform;
    }
}
```

//My component

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private dataService:DataService){}
  ngOnInit(){
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe((data:any)=> {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

//the asset/data.json

```
[
    {"key":"uno"},
    {"key":"dos"},
    {"key":"tres"},
    {"key":"cuatro"},
    {"key":"cinco"}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own Observable that wraps the http.get and return your manipulated response, in this example it is the manipulatedAccountsResponse object:

```
getAll(): Observable<AccountsResponse> {
  return Observable.create(observer => {
    this.http.get<AccountsResponse>('/accounts')
             .subscribe((result) => {
               const manipulatedAccountsResponse = result;
               // do something with result.
               manipulatedAccountsResponse.setTotal(100);
               observer.next(manipulatedAccountsResponse);
               // call complete if you want to close this stream (like a promise)
               observer.complete();
            });
  });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As per my consideration you can call function of that service in your success responce and process your data in function and return it to back it.

```js
return this.http.get(url, {headers: this.headers}).map(
      (response: Response) => {
        const data = response.json();
        return this.processData(data);
      }
    ).catch(
      (error: Response) => {
        return Observable.throw(error);
      }
    );
    
public processData(data : any){
  //process your data
  return data;//this is processed data
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have read my question? That's the depricated service!

Comment: Your question is how to process data which is returning in responce and how we treat our data is not part of any documentation.

Comment: Yes, but `.map` is not supported on the `HttpClient`!

Comment: Correct, because map has been removed from RxJs 6. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

In the "new" Httpclient, get return yet a json response by default. Then you only write

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'; //<--HttpClient
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';                  //import the operator "map"
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'; //and the operator "catch"

....
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {} //<--sure HttpClient
...
return this.http.get(url).map(  //yet get "data"
      (data:any) => {
        return this.processData(data);
      }
    ).catch(
      (error: Response) => {
        return Observable.throw(error);
      }
    );

public processData(data : any){
  //process your data
  return data;//this is processed data
}
```

Comment: Are you sure there is a `map` in `HttpClient`? Just do a `ctrl+f` on **[official document](https://angular.io/guide/http)**

Comment: I just coded my answer and work. "map" is not a operator of HttpClient, just a operator of Observables in Rxjs library like switchMap,of,shareReply...,. I used Angular 5.0.0

Comment: @AJT_82 But they did not write anything about `map` in the official doc about `HttpClient`

Comment: the only thing you must do is import all the operators you need, remove const data = response.json();. and take account that get() return "data" itself

Comment: @Eliseo The point is that I need to modify the response of `get`. I'm not going to use it like most of the common use cases and inside the component. I'm going to use it in a service, the service `return`s the `get` and I want to **modify** the response before `return` it to the component which is subscribing to the service.

Comment: I add a full example, I hope it can help you